# How to send bytes over a socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets, hex, byte

so I need to send a bunch of escaped hex to a server but I need to know which a causing problems. I tried the code below but I cant get it to send raw bytes. It keeps outputting the string. Im new to programming in general so am I missing something basic? I searched it but nothing helpful.

```
`ops = ''.join('\\x%02x' % i for i in range(256))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(5)
s.connect((127.0.0.1,8888))
s.send(ops)
s.close()`
```

Comment: I can show you how to do this. What is the exact string of bytes that you want to send?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is an escaped hex? You either want to send bytes or strings. Byte is a byte, it's a number:

```
ops = bytearray(i for i in range(256))
```

Comment: Hi sorry it was 5 in the morning when I posted that. I think I meant escaped characters, but what I was after is how to send bytes like an unsigned char buffer in C. Im a bit more awake now and have it worked out. Thanks!